# Chrome displaying Failed to load resource

Tags: html

I have a simple webpage structure:

```
-index.html
-css
  -style.css
```

The contents of the html are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the html in Chrome I get the error:

> Failed to load resource file:///C:/css/style.css

My directory is in Mydocuments in Windows. Why can't the .css file be found?

Comment: Try `href="css/style.css"`.

Comment: You meant `css/style.css` without the slash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the console shows, your path

```
/css/style.css
```

means "the 'css' directory in the root path":

```
C:/css/style.css
```

which is not what you want*.

Use `css/style.css` - this will mean "the 'css' sub-directory in the directory the current page's located in."

<sub>* But even if it *had* been what you want, access to local `file://` URLs is limited in that any resources you request (images, style sheets) need to be in a sub-directory of the current page. Modern browsers impose this limitation for security reasons.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Forward slash first means an absolute path (from the root). Since you are running your page from the file system, the root is the drive.

No forward slash first means a relative path (from the current folder).

You may also want to make a shortcut to your chrome browser that has the "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag, so you can better test your site locally as you add more advanced features.